# Create name of path files from list

Tags: python, loops, list

I want to create path of files from list.

```
pathList = [['~/workspace'], ['test'], ['*'], ['*A', '*2'], ['*Z?', '*1??'], ['*'], ['*'], ['*'], ['*.*']]
```

and I want

```
[['', '~/workspace', 'test', '*', '*A', '*Z?', '*', '*', '*', '*.*']]

[['', '~/workspace', 'test', '*', '*A', '*1??', '*', '*', '*', '*.*']]

[['', '~/workspace', 'test', '*', '*2', '*Z?', '*', '*', '*', '*.*']]

[['', '~/workspace', 'test', '*', '*2', '*1??', '*', '*', '*', '*.*']]
```

I try to create it from for loop but I get

```
[['', '~/workspace', 'test', '*', '*A', '*Z?', '*', '*', '*', '*.*', '*1??', '*', '*', '*', '*.*', '*2', '*Z?', '*', '*', '*', '*.*', '*1??', '*', '*', '*', '*.*']]
```

How can I do? Please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: itertools.product, it work. Thank you very much for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.6 or newer you can use [**`itertools.product`**](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
for x in itertools.product(*pathList):
    print x
```

Answer (score 2):

Anticipating the next step - you can create paths like this

```
>>> import os, itertools
>>> [os.path.join(*x) for x in  itertools.product(*pathList)]
['~/workspace/test/*/*A/*Z?/*/*/*/*.*',
 '~/workspace/test/*/*A/*1??/*/*/*/*.*',
 '~/workspace/test/*/*2/*Z?/*/*/*/*.*',
 '~/workspace/test/*/*2/*1??/*/*/*/*.*']
```

and here is a version using [itertools.starmap](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap)

```
>>> from itertools import starmap
>>> starmap(os.path.join, itertools.product(*pathList))
<itertools.starmap object at 0xb77d948c>
>>> list(_)
['~/workspace/test/*/*A/*Z?/*/*/*/*.*',
 '~/workspace/test/*/*A/*1??/*/*/*/*.*',
 '~/workspace/test/*/*2/*Z?/*/*/*/*.*',
 '~/workspace/test/*/*2/*1??/*/*/*/*.*']
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but I think you want [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
print( list( itertools.product( *pathList ) ) )
>>> [('~/workspace', 'test', '*', '*A', '*Z?', '*', '*', '*', '*.*'), 
    ('~/workspace', 'test', '*', '*A', '*1??', '*', '*', '*', '*.*'), 
    ('~/workspace', 'test', '*', '*2', '*Z?', '*', '*', '*', '*.*'), 
    ('~/workspace', 'test', '*', '*2', '*1??', '*', '*', '*', '*.*')]
```

This yield all possible paths, taking one element from each nested list.